# is it possible to use to where in firebase with flutter

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

Im trying to retrieve from firebase based on two conditions
`

```
     final medResult = await userMedDB.userMedCollection
    .where('userID', isEqualTo: Auth().uID)
    .where('name', isEqualTo: medName)
    .get();
```

`
is that code correct??

Answer (score 0):

If you're trying to query [google-cloud-firestore](/questions/tagged/google-cloud-firestore) (you tagged with [firebase-realtime-database](/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database), which is a different database) the code is correct.

If your query doesn't work when you add the second condition, you may be missing a composite index that is needed for this query. In that case, can any errors that may happen, log them to the console, and find the link in the error message. This link takes you directly to the Firebase console with all values filled in to create the correct index at the click of a button.

Comment: what do you mean by composite index?

Comment: An index across multiple fields. Also see: https://www.google.com/search?q=firestore+composite+index